# communication through wifi in two android devices

Tags: android, android-wifi

I want to send and receive data between two android devices through wifi. How to do this? I had tried to search for this but not got any simple and well written tutorial. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you read/tried this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks for response but Wi-Fi peer-to-peer (P2P) allows Android 4.0 (API level 14) or later devices with the appropriate hardware to connect directly to each other via Wi-Fi without an intermediate access point. I want to communicate or transfer data between two android devices which have platform 2.2 or later

Comment: Wifi Direct (ad-hoc) or two devices connected to the same AP (infrastructure)?

Comment: @323go two devices connected to the same AP (infrastructure)?

Comment: Why don't you use Bluetooth instead? If the devices share the same AP then they will most likely be close enough to pair to each other.

Comment: Bluetooth is a pain @en4bz. You'll have to pair first, discover services, etc. Wifi socket communication is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the basics of socket programming, the main issue is finding each other on the same network. Starting with API Level 14, you can use [Network Service Discovery](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html). Prior to that, [jmDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/) is a good, workable choice. The NSD link also contains a sample chat application, which gives you an example of how to communicate between to devices using a socket.